# CLIPS LHS match multislot

Tags: clips, expert-system, inference-engine

I wrote this rule for an expert system :

```
    (defrule wild chicory
      (attribute (name habitat) (value sea montain grassland unknown))   
=>
      (assert (plant "Cichorium_Intybus"))
    )
```

However I don't want the habitat's value to match all of the values that I have given, but to only match at least one of values.
I'm wondering how I should do this. I could do it so:

```
(defrule wild chicory
          (or (attribute (name habitat) (value sea)) 
              (attribute (name habitat) (value mountain))
              (attribute (name habitat) (value grassland))
              (attribute (name habitat) (value unknow))
          )
          =>
          (assert (plant "Cichorium_Intybus"))
)
```

But I would like to know if there is a better solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If value is a single field slot, do it this way:

```
(defrule wild chicory
  (attribute (name habitat) (value sea | mountain | grassland | unknown)) 
  =>
  (assert (plant "Cichorium_Intybus")))
```

If value is a multi field slot, do it this way:

```
(defrule wild chicory
  (attribute (name habitat) (value $? sea | mountain | grassland | unknown $?)) 
  =>
  (assert (plant "Cichorium_Intybus")))
```